# When we use "left" property in an animate function in jquery, does it mean offset().left or position().left?

Tags: jquery, css

Here is it manipulating the `$("#mydiv").position().left` or `$("#mydiv").offset().left`?

```
$("#mydiv").animate({"left":"-100"},1000,"swing");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Neither.**

You are simply animating the [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) property of the element. The [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) of the element and it's parents sets how that property's value is used, if it is used at all.

Comment: If I want to change only $("#mydiv").position().left, how should I accomplish that ?

Comment: @HoneyThakuria It depends. `position()` is relative to the offset parent, so you could just `position:relative;` the element and set the `left` property, or give it a negative margin

Comment: Yes got it. It means if no ancestors are positioned relative than it will be offset else position. Thanks. Also tell me whether is it advisable to use Jquery for DOM Manipulation while using Framework like AngularJS ? or should use their native methods like ng-class ?

Comment: @HoneyThakuria I suppose that would be a matter of opinion, but I don't see anything wrong with it.